# Random walk with incommensurate steps

Tags: combinatorics, random-walk

Anyone seen any research on random walks with steps +q/-1, where q is irrational? I am interested in probability of staying positive for n steps.
Alternative formulation would be steps of size 1 either up or to the right. And one would be looking at the probability to stay above a line with irrational slope.